# Store drawable or bitmap in internal storage

Tags: java, android, arraylist, drawable, internal-storage

I have a object with two string values and one drawable (or it may be bitmap - doesn't matters). I get pictures from the WEB. In my project I need to save couple of that objects in ArrayList for further use.

That ArrayList used to fill the ListView with custom adapter.

Now I using those methods for write and read ArrayList from file. It use serialization.

```
public final class InternalStorage{

private InternalStorage() {}

public static void writeObject(Context context, String key, Object object) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(key, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
}

public static Object readObject(Context context, String key) throws IOException,
        ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(key);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    Object object = ois.readObject();
    return object;
} }
```

Problem is Drawable or Bitmap objects are not serializable.
So what I suppose to do to store drawables along with every serialized object of ArrayList?
Maybe I need somehow associate every stored image file with every ArrayList item? And how to read It after all?

Thanks for answers and sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you do not want to serialize the bitmap anyway as pure pixel-buffer would be to big. use the compress method at Bitmap

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
immage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
```

Comment: And When I compress it - it just save the file to Internal srorage, right? So how I can associate these file with my Object and, finally, read it for using in ListView adapter?

Answer (score 1):

save the ByteArray of those images then you can restore it.

Use these functions..

```
 public static byte[] convert(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
    byte[] array = stream.toByteArray();
    stream.close();
    return array;


}
public static Bitmap convert(byte[] array) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(array,0,array.length);
}
```